# Android Studio Build: failed Unknown type T

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build

Hoping someone can help. I've been at this hours and cannot figure it out. All of a sudden my Android Studio project has stopped building. All I get in the Build Output console is

**Build: failed Unknown type T**

No stack trace or any other information, to suggest where the error might be. I've been through every line of code looking for errors and typos, but I can't see anything. It was working fine, now all of a sudden it isn't.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Kind regards,
Marc